# How to fix "... the remote repository doesn't support SHA-256/512"

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

Just making a Spring Boot project by IntelliJ IDEA, using gradle 7.5 and kotlin 1.6.21, and using the plugin `maven-publish` to publish jar to a private nexus repository.
But the console shows:

```
Cannot upload checksum for snapshot-maven-metadata.xml because the remote repository doesn't support SHA-256. This will not fail the build.
Cannot upload checksum for snapshot-maven-metadata.xml because the remote repository doesn't support SHA-512. This will not fail the build.
Cannot upload checksum for module-maven-metadata.xml because the remote repository doesn't support SHA-256. This will not fail the build.
Cannot upload checksum for module-maven-metadata.xml because the remote repository doesn't support SHA-512. This will not fail the build.
```

I found some suggest like "set systemProp.org.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure=true in gradle.properties", but it does'nt help for me because it using gradle wrapper to manage project and I can't find   `gradle.properties`.

How should I do?

Comment: Create a `gradle.properties` file in the root of the project, in the same directory as `settings.gradle.kts`. Add the property into the new `gradle.properties` file. Additionally you can add a flag `-Dorg.gradle.internal.publish.checksums.insecure=true` when running from the command line, https://docs.gradle.org/6.0.1/release-notes.html#publication-of-sha256-and-sha512-checksums